# Application of Cauchy residue theorem to Matsubara sums

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, path-integral, complex-numbers, propagator

For reference, this derivation is closely related to the discussion on pp. 169-173 of [Altland and Simons](https://books.google.com/books/about/Condensed_Matter_Field_Theory.html?id=GpF0Pgo8CqAC&source=kp_book_description). In quantum field theory (specifically when calculating free fermionic propagators via coherent state path integral), we encounter the following sum:
$$I_{\beta}(\tau,\tau')\mathrel{\mathop:}= \frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-i\omega_n(\tau-\tau')}}{-i\omega_n+E}$$
where $0\leq\tau'\leq\tau\leq\beta$ and $\omega_n=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{\beta}$ is called the Matsubara frequency. We want to evaluate this sum, with the final answer being
$$I_{\beta}(\tau,\tau')=\frac{e^{-E(\tau-\tau')}}{e^{-\beta E}+1}$$
While I am very close to obtaining this, I'm missing one step. Let me share what I have so far. I define two functions. The first is
$$f_\beta(z)=\frac{\beta}{e^{-\beta z}+1}$$
which has infinitely many poles along the imaginary axis at $z_n=i\omega_n$. It is easy to show that $z_n$ is a simple pole, and that the residue of $f$ at $z_n$ is 1. Next, I define
$$g(z;\tau,\tau')=\frac{e^{-z(\tau-\tau')}}{-z+E}$$
It clearly has a simple pole at $z=E$. I then define the region $S$ to be the rectangle going from $-i\infty$ to $+i\infty$ along the imaginary axis and $-x$ to $x$ along the real axis (where $x < E$ so that the pole of $g$ is not contained in $S$). By Cauchy residue theorem,
$$\begin{align}
    \frac{1}{\beta}\oint_{\gamma=\partial S}\  \frac{dz}{2\pi i}\ g(z; \tau, \tau') f_\beta (z) &= \frac{1}{\beta}\sum_n \text{Res}\left[g(z)f(z), i\omega_n\right]\\
    &= \frac{1}{\beta}\sum_n g(i\omega_n)\\
    &= I_{\beta}(\tau,\tau')
\end{align}$$
To evaluate the integral, we deform the contour $\gamma=\partial S$. The new contour consists of (i) an infinite counterclockwise circle and (ii) a small clockwise circle enclosing $E$ on the real axis (if this part is not clear I can elaborate). If we assume that the integral over (i) vanishes, then we are left with
$$-\frac{1}{\beta}\text{Res}\left[g(z)f(z), E\right]$$
which matches the correct answer I gave above. The problem is that I do not see how the integral over (i) vanishes. We have
$$\begin{align}
    \lim_{|z|\rightarrow \infty}\ \left|g(z;\tau,\tau')f_\beta (z)\right|&= \lim_{|z|\rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{\beta}{-z+E}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{e^{z(\tau'-\tau)}}{e^{-\beta z}+1}\right|\\
\end{align}$$
But this is apparently not zero. For example, suppose $\tau'\neq\tau$. It seems the sign of the exponent in the numerator can be positive or negative depending on the sign of $\text{Re}(z)$. The infinite contour can be subdivided into two halves, one with positive real part and one with negative real part. So there is specifically a problem with the left half.

Am I not calculating this limit correctly? Alternatively, did I make a mistake elsewhere in my approach? Is there a better method/function to choose to evaluate the sum?

EDIT: As @naturallyInconsistent correctly pointed out, we need to be a little more precise when applying complex analysis here. In particular, the form of the [ML theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) contains the arc length of the contour. We want to show that $M\cdot L\rightarrow0$ as $|z|\rightarrow\infty$.

Consider the case $\Delta\tau>0$, i.e., unequal imaginary time. The response makes it very clear that $M\cdot L\rightarrow0$ for $\text{Re}(z)\neq0$. An interesting question is what happens at $0\pm i\infty$. Letting $y=\text{Im}(z)$, the modulus of the integrand looks like
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{|y|}\cdot\frac{1}{|e^{-i\beta y} + 1|}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{|y|}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(1+\cos \beta y)}}
\end{align}
The denominator in the right-most fraction oscillates between $0$ and $2$. In particular, it is $0$ when $y=\omega_n$ and $2$ when $y=(2n+2)\frac{\pi}{\beta}$, i.e., half way between $\omega_n$ and $\omega_{n+1}$. My idea is that the original rectangular contour $\gamma$ encloses all Matsubara frequencies, and so the circular one must do the same. Hence, we could discretize the limit such that the circle never intersects a pole. For example, if the radius always sits in the middle of two adjacent $\omega$, then the factor is always $1/2$. Of course, we still encounter the problem that $M\cdot L$ does not seem to vanish, but it least it does not diverge. Does this line of reasoning hold any merit?

Next, we need to address the point made by @naturallyInconsistent about equal imaginary time. I find
\begin{align}
M\cdot L &\rightarrow \frac{1}{|e^{-\beta z} + 1|}\\
&=\frac{1}{|e^{-\beta x} + e^{i\beta y}|}
\end{align}
where $x = \text{Re}(z)$. In light of the previous discussion, let's ignore the case $x = 0$ for now. If $x<0$, then the whole thing goes to zero, which is what we want. The problem is that when $x>0$, the whole thing goes to $1$. So the most we can say is the modulus of the integral is bounded by $1$. I'm not really sure how to resolve this.

It might be helpful to consider the idea of imaginary time ordering more generally. We could first solve the problem for $\Delta\tau>0$ and then take the limit as $\Delta\tau\rightarrow0^+$. I find the answer to be $n_F(-E)$ where $n_F$ is the [Fermi-Dirac distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics#Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_distribution). From the identity $n(E)+n(-E)=1$ (very easy to show), this is equivalent to $1-n_F(E)$. Meanwhile, we could try to evaluate the sum for $\Delta\tau < 0$. We just update the function $f_\beta\rightarrow f'_\beta = f_{-\beta}$ and one can easily verify that the rest of the derivation is the same. The final answer is
$$-\frac{e^{-E(\tau-\tau')}}{e^{+\beta E}+1}$$
which approaches $-n_F(E)$ in the limit as $\Delta\tau\rightarrow0^-$. So the difference between the right-sided and left-sided limits is $1$. I understand that this is somehow due to the fermionic anti-commutation relations, but if someone could elaborate on this further, I would appreciate it. Moreover, does this result give us any insight as to why the infinite contour integral does not seem to vanish?

Comment: Which edition? Which equation number?

Comment: I'm looking at the 2nd ed., specifically the discussion starting with Eqn. 4.36 on p. 170 in the section labelled "INFO". My notation differs slightly because I was trying to work it out on my own before finding it in At. & Si. -- my apologies for that!

Answer (score 2):

You are already almost there. You have to now insert the initially assumed inequalities, in particular,
$$\tag10\leqslant\tau^\prime\leqslant\tau\leqslant\beta\qquad\implies\qquad0\leqslant\tau-\tau^\prime\leqslant\beta$$
There are still the pathological cases $(\tau,\tau^\prime)=(\beta,0)$ and $\tau=\tau^\prime$. Let us ignore them for now, and I will remind you about this at the end. For less typing on my part, let $\Delta\tau=\tau-\tau^\prime>0$. Then you are trying to prove that
$$\tag2\lim_{|z|\to\infty}2\pi|z|\left|\frac\beta{-z+E}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{e^{-z\Delta\tau}}{e^{-z\beta}+1}\right|=0$$
where the $2\pi|z|$ is coming from the length of the huge circular contour. To prove the above result, you actually should break this into two semi-circles, for the left half plane and the right half plane. This is actually extremely natural, because the original contour $\gamma=\partial S$ was originally already of that form, left and right of the imaginary axis. As you correctly noted, the right half plane with $\Re(z)>0$ trivially causes the limit to vanish. We are thus only needing to consider the left half plane.

On the left half plane, we have
$$\tag3\pi|z|\left|\frac\beta{-z+E}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{e^{-z\Delta\tau}}{e^{-z\beta}+1}\right|=\frac{\pi\beta}{\left|1-\frac Ez\right|}\cdot\left|\frac{e^{z(\beta-\Delta\tau)}}{1+e^{z\beta}}\right|\qquad\to\qquad\frac{\pi\beta}1\cdot\frac01=0$$
And so your part (i) vanishes, as required.

Actually, thank you for this question and you putting this much effort into it. I was also confused about this when I came across this before, and I was missing your initial efforts. Now I also get to understand this.

Finally, can you check if the cases of $\Delta\tau=\tau-\tau^\prime=0$ or $\beta$ are impossible? Because the above arguments will break down if they are those values.

Comment: It is an important result in the condensed matter application of QFT, particularly in Matsubara sums. When people hear of QFT these days, they usually think of the SR QFT, the Standard Model, and so forth, not the condensed matter QFT.

Comment: Sorry! I was typing my response and accidentally sent it before I was finished. Anyway, as I said in my original comment, I really do appreciate this discussion. I had also talked about it with my advisor, and we came to the same conclusion as you, at least for unequal time. The rest of my response exceeds the character limit, so please see the edit to my original post.

Comment: I looked up the book again and found that what you are doing is quite far from what they are doing, so I am going to have to come back another day to straighten things out.